# How to access an existing git repository through the terminal git bash?

Tags: git, bash, github

I have a GitHub repository, that I now want to access and then branch.  I created the repository using GitHub desktop.  However I would like to access this repository through the terminal and then branch it.   I have tried the cd as the url link, and the following in the terminal:

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/tracyandgrant/Documents/Treehouse notes/portfolio/.git/

$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        experience.html
        images/
        index.html
        styles.css

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in styles.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

$ git commit -m 'initial commit with git bash'
[master 8c29fcb] initial commit with git bash
 9 files changed, 509 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 experience.html
 create mode 100644 images/WorldMap.gif
 create mode 100644 images/github.svg
 create mode 100644 images/kiwiicon.jpg
 create mode 100644 images/landscape.jpg
 create mode 100644 images/otago-logo.png
 create mode 100644 images/treehouse.png
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 styles.css

$ git remote add origin git@github.com:TracyExcell/Portfolio.git

$ git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/TracyExcell/Portfolio
fatal: remote origin already exists.


$ cd https://github.com/TracyExcell/Portfolio
bash: cd: https://github.com/TracyExcell/Portfolio: No such file or directory
```

If you know how to do this could you please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the docs first on how to brach, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Comment: I think you need to set up ssh certificates so that you can connect to the repo and push. https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

you should not need to re-initialize a repo. What you want to do is fork a repository if it's not yours and set up a separate remotes - named upstream and origin. Branching is external to that concern but you will see 2 sets of remote tracking branches.